# Sitecore SXA CSS Changes not importing with Creative Exchange

Tags: sxa

I created a new site and added few basic components like Rich-Text and Image

I then followed below did below changes after reading few articles.

1) Duplicate Basic2 Theme with ExploreSXABasic2
2) Changed Theme in Settings - /sitecore/content/Tenants/exploresxa/Explore-SXA/Settings -- Compatible themes:
3) Selected Theme in Experience Editor -- ExploreSXABasic2
4) Export Theme
5) Edit index.html and component-richtext-content
[image]
6) Import Theme

I added a class after add-your-css-classes-here in index.html -- It is imported properly. And I can see that in Selected Styles.
[image]

But changes done in component-richtext-content are not imported.

Comment: When you say "they are not imported" do you mean you don't see the changes in the browser? Have you validated on the server that the changes made it to the server? Just wondering if this is a browser cache issue.

Comment: CSS (file) changes are not updating in Sitecore.
I don't see the change in file statistics and also I tried to download and see the changes. But no luck

Comment: Have you changed the theme on the Website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system won't allow updating the default themes -- So even if we update, it won't import, We have to create a new theme while creating the Site. And in Step 3 select the newly created theme. The new theme will be created at path: /sitecore/media library/Themes/(Sitecore Tenant Folder)/(SXA Site)/

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I got the same problem and my custom.css style   is not uploaded even the creative exchange says 'The import has succeeded.'

Comment: Have you created the new theme?
It will only update the new theme and if you are using the default theme it won't' import and you'll see the succeeded message.

Comment: Yes, I am using my own theme prior to the export'

Comment: Please try to create the zip of:
1) - (Folder)
2) sitecore%20modules (Folder)
3) index.html
For reference see - http://nikkipunjabi.com/Sitecore/stackoverflow/sxa.png

And then try.